# Merge 2 Object Array Data Series That Share the Same [0] Index

Tags: c#, arrays, json, object

So let's say that you have 2 series of data.  (Both object arrays, in your choice of a serialized JSON string, or the actual objects).

For Instance:

```
string str1 = @"{""datapoints"":[[""02/28/2019"",146800.0],[""02/27/2019"",147700.0],[""02/26/2019"",153900.0]]}";
```

Then, you have a second series that is very similar...

```
string str2 = @"{""datapoints"":[[""02/28/2019"",145600.0],[""02/27/2019"",143600.0],[""02/26/2019"",152200.0]]}";
```

Note: the object arrays inside are both a length of "2", and both contain the same "date" as the [0] index.

How does one merge the 2 object arrays into 1, to yield the following output...

```
string str3 = @"{""datapoints"":[[""02/28/2019"",145600.0,145600.0],[""02/27/2019"",143600.0,143600.0],[""02/26/2019"",152200.0,152200.0]]}";
```

For clarity, I'm interested in using the [0] index once, and merging the [1] indexes together.  (the number values)

Extra credit if this can be a loop, or can be done with any number of series.

Comment: I don't understand your merge logic - the values in your `str3` don't correspond to the values in `str1` or `str2`.  For instance the first entries in `str1` and `str2` are `["02/28/2019",146800.0]` and `["02/28/2019",145600.0]` but your expected JSON has `["02/28/2019",145600.0,145600.0]` which does not include `146800.0` at all.  Is this a mistake in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net), you can deserialize each JSON sample to an object that contains a `datapoints` property that is an enumerable of object arrays, then merge them using the LINQ methods [`GroupBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [`Aggregate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Aggregate__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____1_System_Func___1___0___1__System_Func___1___2__).

Say the JSON samples to be merged are in a `string [][] jsonSeriesList` like so:

```
string str1 = @"{""datapoints"":[[""02/28/2019"",146800.0],[""02/27/2019"",147700.0],[""02/26/2019"",153900.0]]}";
string str2 = @"{""datapoints"":[[""02/28/2019"",145600.0],[""02/27/2019"",143600.0],[""02/26/2019"",152200.0]]}";
var jsonSeriesList = new[] { str1, str2 }; // Add others as required
```

Then you can create a combined series as follows:

```
var merged = jsonSeriesList.Aggregate(
    new { datapoints = Enumerable.Empty<object[]>() },
    (m, j) => new
    {
        datapoints = m.datapoints.Concat(JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(j, m).datapoints)
            // Group them by the first array item.
            // This will throw an exception if any of the arrays are empty.
            .GroupBy(i => i[0])
            // And create a combined array consisting of the key (the first item from all the grouped arrays)
            // concatenated with all subsequent items in the grouped arrays.
            .Select(g => new[] { g.Key }.Concat(g.SelectMany(i => i.Skip(1))).ToArray())
    });

var mergedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(merged);
```

Notes:

- I am deserializing to an anonymous type for brevity.  You could create an explicit data model if you prefer.
- I am assuming the individual datapoint arrays all have at least one item.
- There is no attempt to sort the resulting merged JSON by series date.  You could do that if necessary.
- The solution assumes that you will never have multiple component arrays in the same series with the same first item, e.g. `"02/28/2019"` repeated twice.  If so, they will get merged also.

Sample .Net fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CvI7wW).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified example (simplified as validations might be required, but hope it given you a place to start):

1. Convert it into dot net object
2. Then go through each date point - for each date point go through all the series, adding the values.

`//container object for the json series
        public class Container
        {
            public List<List<object>> datapoints;
        }`

```
    //Input series in JSON 
    string[] inputSeries = new string[]
        {
            "{\"datapoints\": [[\"02/28/2019\", 146800.0],[\"02/27/2019\", 147700.0],[\"02/26/2019\", 153900.0]]}",
            "{\"datapoints\": [[\"02/28/2019\", 145600.0],[\"02/27/2019\", 143600.0],[\"02/26/2019\", 152200.0]]}"
        };

        //Container for input series in dot net object
        List<Container> con = new List<Container>();

        foreach (var series in inputSeries)
        {
            con.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Container>(series));
        }

        // output container
        Container output = new Container();
        output.datapoints = new List<List<object>>();

        // assuming all series have equal number of data points.....might not be so
        for (int i = 0; i < con[0].datapoints.Count; i++)
        {
            output.datapoints.Add(new List<object>());
            // inner loop is to go across series for the same datapoint....
            for (int j = 0; j < con.Count; j++)
            {
                // add the date if this is the first series....after that only add the values
                // right now the assumption is that the dates are in order and match....validation logic might be required
                if (j == 0)
                {
                    output.datapoints[i].Add(con[j].datapoints[i][0]);
                    output.datapoints[i].Add(con[j].datapoints[i][1]);
                }
                else
                {
                    output.datapoints[i].Add(con[j].datapoints[i][1]);
                }
            }
        }
```